# Insufficient privileges for Salesforce Platform Licensed user when trying to access dashboards but able to access reports

Tags: dashboard, userlicense, insufficient-privileges

I have a user which Salesforce Platform License and this user is added to a public group.Dashboard folder has been shared to this public group.

But when I am log-in with this user,I am able to see dashboard folder but on clicking on dashboard,it shows Insufficient privileges error message.Also,this user is able to see reports from other folder that has been shared to this group.

User's profile has Create and Customize Dashboards,Edit My Dashboards and View Dashboards in Public Folders access.

Comment: Ok, platform licence definitely is able to access dashboards. Try seeing if the user has access to the folder the reports that make up the dashboard is in.

Comment: Yes, User has access to report folder that is being used for dashboard.User is having Read access on those reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much brainstorming,finally dashboard is visible for the desired user.

I have changed 'View dashboard as' from Salesforce user to Salesforce Platform user and 'Dashboard Running User' is 'Run as logged-in user'.

So now dashboard is visible to users having Salesforce and SalesForce Platform user License.

Answer (score 0):

This work-around was fine in salesforce classic, but lightning doesn't allow you to save a different "View dashboard as" user while specifying to run as the logged-in user.

In lightning the only way to have a dashboard run as the logged in user when that user has a platform license is to log in as a platform user to edit and save the dashboard (with "View dashboard as" set to "The logged in user").